# Size of a matrix is too big to fit inside text block

Tags: margins, matrices, arrays

I know there's other topics with this kind of question, but I tried a few solutions and just got errors...

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %code
\usepackage{uarial} % for
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %arial font

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}    
\begin{document}
        \begin{align}
        \textbf{A}_C&= \left[ \begin{array}{ccccccc}
        -1.6304 \cdot 10^4  &  0.5110 \cdot 10^4 &  -0.1054 \cdot 10^4  & 0.2631 \cdot 10^4  & -0.0986 \cdot 10^4 &   0.0023 \cdot 10^4 &   0.0032 \cdot 10^4 \\
        0  & -0.4217 \cdot 10^4  &  0.2283 \cdot 10^4 &   0.0327 \cdot 10^4 & 0.0231 \cdot 10^4   & -23.1643  & -13.2699   \\
        0  &       0  & -0.0640 \cdot 10^4 &   0.0133 \cdot 10^4 &  -0.0197 \cdot 10^4 &  11.4743 &  8.2354  \\
        0  &       0    &     0 &  -0.0196 \cdot 10^4 &   0.0110 \cdot 10^4  & -2.5950  & -2.8107 \\
        0  &       0    &     0 &        0 &  -62.7970  & -0.1826  & 4.8503  \\
        0  &       0    &     0 &        0  &       0  & -0.5370  & -0.0936  \\
        0  &       0    &     0 &        0  &       0  &       0  & -0.2336
        \end{array} \right] 
        \end{align}
            \end{document}
```

So, if you run this code you can see that the matrix **Ac** is  larger than page width.

Comment: not really relevant to the question, but `align` is meant to be used for multi-line displays.  one-line displays like this one should use `equation`.  (there is a difference in how the spacing is applied above and below the display.)

Comment: @barbara I simplified the code by taking off the other equations from the environment. And I kind of regret about this, because some solutions may not considerer alignment of equations...

Comment: reasonable explanation.  thanks.  (so many people *do* use only `align` that i'm sensitized to it, especially since they then ask why the spacing is different vs. `equation`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My main suggestion is to take the factor `10^4` outside the matrix. That way, the width of first five columns can be made reduced dramatically, while the width of the final two columns doesn't increase much on net. Using a `bmatrix*` environment and reducing the value of the `\arraycolsep` helps too.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{helvet} % I don't have 'uarial' package
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}    
\begin{document}
\hrule  % just to illustrate width of page block
\begin{equation}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default value: 5pt
\textbf{A}_C= 10^4\cdot
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
-1.6304   &  0.5110  & -0.1054  &   0.2631  &  -0.0986  &  0.0023      &  0.0032 \\
       0  & -0.4217  &  0.2283  &   0.0327  &   0.0231  & -0.00231643  & -0.00132699 \\
       0  &       0  & -0.0640  &   0.0133  &  -0.0197  &  0.00114743  &  0.00082354 \\
       0  &       0  &       0  &  -0.0196  &   0.0110  & -0.00025950  & -0.00028107 \\
       0  &       0  &       0  &        0  &  -0.0063  & -0.00001826  &  0.00048503 \\
       0  &       0  &       0  &        0  &       0   & -0.00005370  & -0.00000936 \\
       0  &       0  &       0  &        0  &       0   &           0  & -0.00002336 \\
\end{bmatrix*} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, took me a while to learn how to install the `mathtools package` but it's allright now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `siunitx` and `ncccmath` for its `\medmath` command, which reduces the size of `\displaystyle` by about 20 %:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %code
\usepackage{uarial} % for
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %arial font
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format =-1.4e1, exponent-product ={ · }}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} & \mathbf{A}_C=& & & & \notag\\
  &\medmath{\left[\begin{array}{S@{\;}SSSS[table-format =-2.4e1]@{\;}S[table-format =-2.4e1]S[table-format =-2.4e1]}
  -1.6304 e4 & 0.5110 e4 & -0.1054 e4 & 0.2631 e4 & -0.0986 e4 & 0.0023 e4 & 0.0032 e4 \\
  0 & -0.4217 e4 & 0.2283 e4 & 0.0327 e4 & 0.0231 e4 & -23.1643 & -13.2699 \\
  0 & 0 & -0.0640 e4 & 0.0133 e4 & -0.0197 e4 & 11.4743 & 8.2354 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -0.0196e4 & 0.0110e4 & -2.5950 & -2.8107 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -62.7970 & -0.1826 & 4.8503 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.5370 & -0.0936 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -0.2336
  \end{array}\right]}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]